# React Antd Tree : Can't convert my class component to functionnal component

Tags: reactjs, tree, antd

I have a provided class component and I'm triyng to convert it into a functionnal component but I get some issues..

[This is the class component code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-moser-fhuuk?file=/index.js)

[And this is my functionnal component code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-leftpad-5sqrvi?file=/index.js) :

This is the output of my class componenent :

[image]

And when I'm trying in my functionnal component it look like that :

[image]

When I click to validate : I just print another Tree with checked data, but in my functionnal component I get -- instead of text :(

I've just create a function to hide the checkbox in subchilds, otherwise it's the same things.
Have you an idea what is the problem please ?

Comment: Can you check your sandbox for functional component again? :) As I'm getting proper tree with check data instead of "--".

Comment: It works! what was the problem ?

Comment: It was already working properly!, I did not make any changes to your code

Comment: Oh great! thank you anyway.. but I got an error in the console : 
"Warning: `children` of Tree is deprecated. Please use `treeData` instead. "

Comment: Is it affecting your tree functionality? It just a warning. You can check this https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22220 for fixing the warning

Comment: Yes I checked it, but when I've tried to remove children and replace it by treeData prop it show an errors..

Comment: This issue is not in your first tree, This warning is shown because of the second tree which is shown after clicking validate button

Comment: Yes I've tried in both, but the issue still there

Comment: Replace your second tree with this code `{state.newTreeView && <Tree treeData={state.newTreeData}></Tree>}`. I hope it helps :)

Comment: The errors still here :(

Comment: For further discussion please use: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242643/discussion-between-ved-and-tania12